# configure: error: --with-ssl=openssl was given, but SSL is not available. の意味

Tags: linux

現在サーバーサイドの環境構築をしているのですが
途中でwgetコマンドが必要になり、インストールしようとすると

`configure: error: --with-ssl=openssl was given, but SSL is not available.`

このようなエラーが返ってきます。
正直意味が解りません。

本当に困っています。
助けてください！！

Comment: 一応意味は: `configure` しようとしたらエラーが出ました: `--with-ssl=openssl` (`openssl` を使ってね!) って言われたけど `SSL` が見当たりません

Comment: ご使用のOSのバージョンと wgetをインストール時に実行したコマンドを質問に追記できますか？

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSLのライブラリがインストールされてないようですね。debian系OSなら、`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`、redhat系なら`sudo yum install -y openssl-devel`を実行してから、もう一度試してみてください。